# want to play audio files wav or mp3 with sudo

Tags: sudo, mp3

The problem persists only when using sudo. for example if I'm using `nvlc <some.mp3>` its working fine. If I use `sudo nvlc <some.mp3>` I can see the gui as processing but can't hear the sound from speaker. I want any package or solution to play an mp3 file with sudo. Is it possible? NOTE:- I must use the command with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

There's an environment variable that is set for your normal user that isn't set (or isn't set to the right thing).

Is there a specific reason you are wanting to use sudo to play audio if playing it with your user id works fine?

P.S.

For reference, this is the variable (as far as I'm aware):
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

**EDIT**

For current session only:
`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000`

You set this as a global root variable if you'd like to keep it instead of needing to set it each time you open a terminal. Can't remember where you set it though, but if you Google "set global root environment variable" you should be able to find it

Comment: yes there's a specific reason..... can you describe a bit better the steps cause m a noob

Comment: I can try! So you need to set the variable. From what I found on Google (and is set on my pi) is /run/user/1000. So using , you first need to set the variable. See edit above for more details.